# About the difference between XGBoost and GBRT

Tags: xgboost, gradient-descent

I'm trying to understand the algorithm of XGboost.

I have several qestions below:

1. What are the fundamental differences between XGboost and gradient boosting classifier(from scikit-learn)?
2. I learned that XGboost uses newton's method for optimization for loss function, but I don't understand what will happen in the case that hessian is nonpositive-definite.

I would be so happy if you help me.